# Extended User search

Tags: discussion, search

How about to extend user search with additional parameters?

It would be nice to see users from specifed location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The location for each user is not standardized at all, since it is just whatever a user happens to put in the profile (if anything at all).  I don't think searching by location would provide many meaningful results.

Comment: There was once a very amusing Data Explorer query on what users had put in their location fields. It was extremely humorous to see how many different ways people could write the same place, with and without misspellings.

Answer (score -1):

It would be easy to set up a location based user data field. I believe it would be very useful. I would like to see this happen.

Comment: So please start new feature request here asking for this, don't hijack existing questions. And no, it won't be easy.